# How I can return an instance of a class using the Builder pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns, builder

I'm trying to create a simple card game. The aim is to have a firmer grasp with C++ (I have experience just with Java up to now). In particular I'm struggling fully understanding the pointers, despite I've read and watched countless materials all over the web.

```
#include "../header_files/Card.h"

class Card {
public:
    void setCardName(const string& name){
        card_name = name;
    }
    void setCardPower(const int& pow){
        card_power = pow;
    }
    void setLuck(const int& luck){
        card_luck = luck;
    }

    void printCardDetails() {
        std::cout << "\nCard: " << card_name
                << "Luck:  "<< card_luck <<
                "Power: " << card_power <<"\n" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    string card_name;
    int card_power;
    int card_luck;
};

class CardBuilder{
public: virtual ~CardBuilder() {};

    Card* getCard(){
        return card.release();
    }
    void createNewCard(){
        card = make_unique<Card>();
    }

    virtual void setCardName() = 0;
    virtual void setCardPower() = 0;
    virtual void setCardLuck() = 0;

protected:
    unique_ptr<Card> card;
};


class CardType1Builder : public CardBuilder {
public:
    virtual ~CardType1Builder() {};

    virtual void setCardName(){
        card->setCardName("Card Type 1");
    }
    virtual void setCardPower(){
        card->setCardPower(1+ (rand() %10));
    }
    virtual void setCardLuck(){
        card->setLuck(1+ (rand() %5));
    }
};

class CardType2Builder : public CardBuilder {
public:
    virtual ~CardType2Builder() {};

    virtual void setCardName(){
        card->setCardName("Card Type 2");  //36
    }
    virtual void setCardPower(){
        card->setCardPower(1+ (rand() %10));
    }
    virtual void setCardLuck(){
        card->setLuck(1+ (rand() %5));
    }
};

class CardGenerator {
public:
    void printCard() {
        cardBuilder->getCard()->printCardDetails();
    }
    void constructCard(CardBuilder* cb){
        cardBuilder = cb;
        cardBuilder->createNewCard();
        cardBuilder->setCardName();
        cardBuilder->setCardPower();
        cardBuilder->setCardLuck();
    }

private:
    CardBuilder* cardBuilder;
};
```

Now I'd like to create a Deck class with several instances of the classes built by the `CardBuilder`. In particular I tried the following:

class Deck{

```
private:
    CardGenerator cardGenerator;
    CardType1Builder cardType1Builder;
    CardType1Builder cardType2Builder;
    Card card1;
    Card card2;  

public:
void generateCards() {
    card1 = *cardGenerator.constructCard(&cardType1Builder); //trying to dereference the pointer
    cardGenerator.printCard();

    card1 cardGenerator.constructCard(&cardType2Builder);
    cardGenerator.printCard();


}
};
```

But unfortunately doesn't work, I probably misunderstood the aim of the * operator. Thank you.

Comment: What doesnt work? Please clarify your question to include what is actually the problem

Comment: `Card* getCard(){ return card.release(); }` since you are transferring ownership, the return type should be a `std::unique_ptr<Card>`.

Comment: Also in C++ `int` is a basic type, so pass it by value instead of by reference (the `&`)

Answer (score 1):

You have not misunderstood the `*` operator (at least I dont think).

This line here wont compile

```cpp
card1 = *cardGenerator.constructCard(&cardType1Builder);
```

This is because `cardGenerator` is an *automatic* object, not a pointer. In C++ objects can be constructed as automatic or dynamic objects. Where automatic objects have lifetimes managed by their scope, dynamic objects exist until manually deleted (or your programs stops executing) and are accessed through pointers. Simply remove the `*` from `cardGenerator` and it should compile and run fine.

Side note: `int` is a basic type in C++, that means you should pass it by value and not by reference (especially since on some systems `int` is actually smaller than a pointer (a reference is simply a const pointer))

Comment: stack => Should be automatic.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Heap and stack or bad concepts to think about in C++ (they are not part of the language concept). You should be thinking of automatic and dynamic storage duration objects. Automatic objects can appear on what java developers would call the heap, but they also exist on what java developers call the stack. This is why they are best referred to as automatic objects. This does not limit the location where they are created but describes how they work. Automatic objects are automatically created and destroyed. Dynamic objects are created with `new` and destroyed with `delete` exist in heap and stack

Comment: I see your point but I think its just two ways of saying the same thing. When I say the heap im not suggesting the memory in it isnt physically in the same place as stack memory but that it is allocated and deallocated in different ways. I was trying to make the distinction between java objects which (as far as i understand) are all pointers and c++ objects which are not

Comment: The problem is it's not necessarily saying the same thing. It often is. You are likely to go through your whole career and use nothing but stack-based Automatic storage. But it isn't always true. Plus, and this is the big point, Automatic better describes what's going on than the word stack. Programming is all about describing behaviours. Automatic describes the behaviour. Stack describes an implementation. It only contains implied information about what is happening.

Comment: Mmmm I do think automatic and dynamic _are_ better names tbh, stack and heap are very much embedded concepts for me though which is interesting and possibly not a good thing :p

Comment: Stack and heap are fine for Java and should be used there. But switching to a new language you need to understand the new paradigm. Also Automatic and Dynamic are not the only types there are also Thread and Static. Each type describes how the object behaves.

Comment: [The Gory Details (as of c++17)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc)

Comment: Unfortunately does not help. This line card1 = cardGenerator.constructCard(&cardType1Builder); is flagged from the IDE "no viable conversion from 'void' to 'Card'. So I tried to modify the constructCard method, changing the return type from void to Card.

Comment: "return cb->getCard();", this time the IDE warns me saying "No viable conversion from returned value of type 'Card*' to function return type 'Card'